# Store and Process Data from 4 AngularJS views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-service

What would be the best way to store radio button input choices on four views and then process them together to load a fifth view? (like a mini survey that then loads either a Win or Lose page)

Ex: if t, t, t, t -> view 5
Ex: if f, f, f, f -> view 6

It seems like services, cookies, ng-storage, local storage are all possibilities, 
but what would be the cleanest way from a front end perspective?

Comment: It really depends on your project and requirements. I can say that I would definitely not use cookies. I would go with a custom angular data service as a wrapper for local/session storage.

Answer (score 0):

It depends largely on how long you need this data to live.  Given your scenario, I'd probably go with an angular service.

Services: Works everywhere and is easy to work with, but only live as long as the SPA lives.  If the user refreshes or leaves and comes back, the data is lost.

Cookies: Can live through a refresh or a leave and come back.  A bit harder to work with.

Local Storage: Same as cookies, but also hard to work with.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be not to use the view for storing the data.

Here I'll give you two options.
First (and also my preference) is to create a service or factory and use that to store the data.
When a submits the form (or selects one of the options) their choice is sent to the service to be stored either as a local variable, or a cookie... or sent to a server... whatever. Do whichever one of those you need, but do it in the service. That makes it easier to change your mind later if you ever want to.

Second (not as recommended) is to have a hierarchical structure to your controllers. You might have one controller that's a parent for all the other controllers. You can then call a function or access variables on the $scope of  the parent controller. I don't recommend this because it can get messy really fast and it's prone to bugs, but I wanted you to know that it's a possibility.